# How to access multiple svn servers?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have two different svn servers containing different repositories that I would like to access from tortoiseSvn. Is there a way to configure to access the two different servers?

Answer (score 1):

In the repository browser just type the URL of the new server you want to access. Previous servers will be added to the  drop down list for future use. Each working copy you download will be linked to its respective server. Can you explain further what problems you are having?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just try to check out some source code from both servers or browse using repository browser. You will be prompted for logins and passwords. You can optionally remember entered credentials so you won't be bothered again and you will be able to work with both repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Every working copy remembers where it came from. So you can use as many servers and repositories as you like without having to configure something.

Of course you need the URL to the repository. But that's enough for svn to work with. And after you checked out a working copy, you don't need to remember that URL anymore because the working copy remembers it for you.